# Multiple errors with BlackRaccoon

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ftp, blackraccoon

I am trying to add black raccoon to my project, added the CFNNetwork.framework to my project and just added the BlackRaccoon folder to project, but I get bunch of errors.
What an I missing? I am using xcode 6 with ios 8.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Need to add `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` into BRRequestError.h